# How to get row handler of an object in DXGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I'm having a DXGrid in Server mode with 100K records, I want to set the focus to the row witch i only have its ID, how could i do that without filtering data.
BTW I'm using XPO as data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was already afraid that it should have something to do with iterating through the rows, get the related object and check the ID. For 100K rows it's not a funny thing to do...After some internet search i came across this [DevExpress Knowledge Base article](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/A1488.aspx) wich basically has the same approach. It's pretty outdated though and they write that this is a desired functionality that they are probably going to develop. It's now about 6 years later, so I think...

If I find anything more helpfull I'll conme back to this question. And you can take the link of mine as a starting point to search any further.

EDIT

Although it's for winform grid's (I think WPF grid's will basically have the same functionality) [this](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument642) could also be interesting.

Comment: The first part is to iterating through the rows, that is totally unacceptable for 100K , for me it takes more then 10 min to find a row. And for the second part, It dose no suite for Server-Mode.

Comment: Hmmmm...already thought it would be tough to do. You can maintain an array (buckets) that would store the rowhandle at the position of the ID (when it's an int) of the related object? At the moment you need to focus a specific Object (based on ID) you simply take the rowhandle from array[ID] and focus it. The array could be generated / maintained in a background worker. The array has to be as big as the biggest ID. It may contain many unfilled positions, takes up some memory but when you need the rowhandle -> picking it from the right bucket is lightning fast O(1). Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmmmmmmmmm...i must notice that my grid is in Server-mode , this means that the whole data is not loaded on the client, and only a portion of data is loaded and that is very obvious because I do not want to load 100k data on the client. So i can not index an array of ID's on client side. The following link might make it clear : http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument8398

Comment: Begins to look pretty impossible what you want to achieve. You can "emulate" a kind of server mode yourself by fetching the data in small portions (paging) on a background worker populating the array I talked about and take a little more control yourself.

Comment: Also, it must be possible to come up with some other UI design that bypasses the use of the grid to display the object you desire (by ID)

Comment: Maybe your right. coming up with another UI might be a good idea! But any idea for a UI ??

Comment: You could retrieve all records for a certain property (type) of the record. For example: when you have persons you could show only men or women in the grid based upon the choiche of the user. This splits the amount of records in two already. Thus slicing up the number of records you want to show simultaneously. 100k records in a grid can be a bad user experience as well.

Comment: I'm so sad that did not found any option except changing my UI strategy.

Comment: Too bad. But dealing with so much records isn't an easy thing. Not everything is possible. Do you have a DevExpress account? You can put your question at their help desk to ask advice. They have an excellent support team.